# How can write a member funtion which can accept any type of class object?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to implement hash map, So I want to write a class which will accept object of any class and based on the object size it will return the result.

example:

```
class A
{
public:
int a;
};

class B
{
char b;
};

my hash map class
??
```

Comment: Are you asking "How do template functions work in C++"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Root base class in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399744/root-base-class-in-c)

Comment: "So I want to write a class which will accept object of any class and based on the object size it will return the result."  I can't figure out what that means, beginning at "and based on...".

Comment: I want a member function which can accept any objects from different class as an argument.

Comment: Your design is based on the false premise that a hash function should only take an object's size into account and not its value.